# Как изменить переменную в функции в зависимости от ширины экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу помощи у того кто может разбираться в этом:
Есть в моем таймере разная ширина экрана:
1200 и больше --- fontSize 30, captionSize 10
от 992 до 1200 --- fontSize  25, captionSize  8
от 768 до 992 - fontSize   17, captionSize  5
Как это присвоить переменной fontSize и captionSize?

```
<script>
        $('#countdown-11').timeTo({
            seconds: 100000,
            displayHours: true,
            displayDays: 2,
            displayCaptions: true,
            fontSize: 20,
            captionSize: 10
        });
</script>
```

Comment: прочитайте про медиа-запросы в css и перекройте стили нужными значениями. не занимайтесь ерундой на js

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MEDIA_VARIABLE = {
  '992' : {
    fontSize: 17,
    captionSize: 5,
  },
  '1200' : {
    fontSize: 25,
    captionSize: 8,
  },
  '9999' : {
    fontSize: 30,
    captionSize: 10,
  }
};
let $width = +$(window).width(),
    currentVariables = {};
    
for ( let breakpoint in MEDIA_VARIABLE) {
  if ( +$width > +breakpoint) continue;
    currentVariables = MEDIA_VARIABLE[breakpoint];
    break;
}

$('#countdown-11').timeTo({
            seconds: 100000,
            displayHours: true,
            displayDays: 2,
            displayCaptions: true,
            fontSize: currentVariables.fontSize || 20,
            captionSize: currentVariables.captionSize || 10
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
Прошу помощи у того кто может разбираться в этом:
Есть в моем таймере разная ширина экрана:
1200 и больше --- fontSize 30, captionSize 10
от 992 до 1200 --- fontSize 25, captionSize 8
от 768 до 992 - fontSize 17, captionSize 5
Как это присвоить переменной fontSize и captionSize?
</pre>
```

Но лучше на CSS решать такие вопросы, через @media

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример решения.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $window_width = $(window).width();
  var $fontSize = 20,$captionSize = 10; // default sizes
  if($window_width >= 1200){
    $fontSize = 30;
    $captionSize = 10;
  }
  else if($window_width >= 992 && $window_width < 1200){
    $fontSize = 25;
    $captionSize = 8;
  }
  else if($window_width >= 768 && $window_width < 992){
    $fontSize = 17;
    $captionSize = 5;
  }
  $('#countdown-11').timeTo({
    seconds: 100000,
    displayHours: true,
    displayDays: 2,
    displayCaptions: true,
    fontSize: $fontSize,
    captionSize: $captionSize
  });
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Срабатывает но только после перезагрузки. но это устраивает!) спасибо!